# Navigate to relative directory contained within project folder

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

I have a program which reads .csv files.  My program lives in my project folder: **\my_directory\my_program.py**

I have moved the .csv files to a sub-directory: **\my_directory\Alphabets\my_csv.csv**

How do I tell my main program to look in the relative directory for this new location path.

All my googling has led me to solutions involving `os` and `Path`, but they seem to produce a string with the folder information. I don't believe this is what I want.

I have tried variations of  `parse_alphabet = '\\Alphabets\\MUTCD_{}_Alpha.csv'.format(alphabet_used)` as seen in other examples, but this has not worked.

```
# This module opens the .csv files, organizes the data contained within and returns a string 

import csv

def csv_reader(alphabet_used):

    parse_alphabet = 'MUTCD_{}_Alpha.csv'.format(alphabet_used)
    with open(parse_alphabet, 'r') as csv_file:
        csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file)

        next(csv_reader)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The leading `\\` in `"\\Alphabets\\MUTCD_{}_Alpha.csv"` is interpreted as an absolute filepath. This becomes `C:\Alphabets\MUTCD_{}_Alpha.csv`

`"Alphabets\\MUTCD_{}_Alpha.csv"` is interpreted as a relative filepath (relative to the Python script). This becomes `C:\path\to\mydirectory\Alphabets\MUTCD_{}_Alpha.csv`